# Do both my GPU and motherboard have to support 4K resolution?

Tags: 4k-resolution

I am building a HTPC. I have a monitor that supports 4K (UHD) at 60Hz refresh rate through the DP. My GPU is the GTX 950, which supports 4K and has a DP1.2. However, my motherboard is a GA-H81M-H, and gigabyte's website says this model only allows 4K at 24Hz. Does that matter? Will I still be able to run at 60Hz?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your motherboards 4k capability is completely independent from your graphics card capability. It is based on the HDMI port on your motherboard, and the onboard graphics to some extent (the [GA-H81M-H](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4737#sp) has HDMI 1.4, which caps out at 24 frames per second).

The [GTX950](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gtx-950/specifications) has an HDMI 2.0 port, which supports 4k frequencies up to 60 frames per second.

Further information about [HDMI 2.0](http://www.cnet.com/news/hdmi-2-0-what-you-need-to-know/)

Comment: So does that mean I wouldn't get 4K @ 60Hz, because the motherboard only supports HDMI 1.4? Or is that irrelevant because the GPU does?

Comment: He means that if you plug in to the HDMI port on your GPU instead of the on-board port you will be able to get 4k 60hz without a problem.